# Read Body Without Signature

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app

Im developing an Applicattion in C# that reads email from exchange using EWS. 
When I get a new email I need to save the Body in a Database and resend it to other email @.
This is already done but the problem is that I should save the new email without the Signature. 
There is any way to identify where does the Signature starts?

Thank you in advanced for help :)

Answer (score 5):

Signature is a part of the Email Body itself. So, if you haven't put an identifier yourself into the email body, it is not possible to separate the email signature from its body.

You can look in the email body for some common words, like `Thanks` or `Regards` using some string matching algorithm. The idea behind this is generally people use this words with their signature. But this is a probability only. You can't be sure about it.